# Meteor and Socket IO - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, meteor, socket.io

I'm trying to connect a client to a server socket and I'm getting this error.

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:9999/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NTQGzyP&b64=1' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I've looked at answers to similar questions and tried them with no change. This includes setting the headers using `WebApp.rawConnectHandlers` and setting the cors options to no avail. I've spent a lot of time copying the different solutions others have mentioned but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

I've tried adding the headers before and after creating the server.

**Client**

```
const io = require("socket.io-client")
const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:9999/")
```

**Server**

```
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import http, * as Http from 'http';
import {Socket} from 'socket.io';
import {WebApp} from "meteor/webapp";

Meteor.startup(() => {

    // Server
    const server: Http.Server = http.createServer();

    WebApp.rawConnectHandlers.use(function (req, res, next) {
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        return next();
    });

    const io = require('socket.io')(server);

    io.on('connection', (socket: Socket)=>{
        socket.on('hello',(data)=>{
            console.log('HELLO BISH')
            console.log(data.text)
        })
    })


    // Start server
    try {
        server.listen(9999);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }

});
```

What is the correct method of allowing the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I had to set the cors configuration for the socket. I allowed `http://localhost:3000` to connect to it which now allows my webpage to communicate with the socket server.

```
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
});
```